# SchemaDefinition.Create throws exception in Microsoft.ML.ImageAnalytics version 2.0

Tags: c#, ml.net, ml.net-model-builder, microsoft.ml

The following line of code

```
SchemaDefinition def = SchemaDefinition.Create(typeof(ImageData), SchemaDefinition.Direction.Read);
```

throws

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Could not determine an IDataView type and registered custom types for member Image (Parameter 'rawType')'
```

when using Microsoft.ML.ImageAnalytics version 2.0.

The same code works with no exceptions in Microsoft.ML.ImageAnalytics version 1.71

The ImageData class is defined as follows:

```
public class ImageData
{
    [ColumnName("image")]

    [ImageType(height:100, width:100)]
    public Bitmap Image { get; set; }
}
```

Is there anything that can be done in order to avoid this exception?

Answer (score 3):

As pointed in the question I did for the same issue, there is a breaking change in ML.NET 2.0 where, due to that System.Drawings is only supported by Windows, they have changed the class for image handling to MLImage (https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/main/docs/release-notes/2.0/release-2.0.0.md#breaking-changes). So, they are suggesting to change the Bitmap class to their MLImage class.