# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException when using Microsoft.ML.Analytics 2.0

Tags: c#, ml.net, ml.net-model-builder, microsoft.ml

I have developed an Object Detection solution in C# using capabilities of the Microsoft.ML package. However, when this package was upgraded to its 2.0 version, the solution started not working.

Doing some research, I have found that, when using the  Microsoft.ML.Analytics dll of 2.0 version the following error arises:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Could not determine an IDataView
> type and registered custom types for member Bitmap (Parameter
> 'rawType')

Which is not appearing when using the dll from the previous version, the 1.71. I have seen that question before ([SchemaDefinition.Create throws exception in Microsoft.ML.ImageAnalytics version 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74897544/schemadefinition-create-throws-exception-in-microsoft-ml-imageanalytics-version)), but no one has managed to answer it yet.

Could you help me to get rid of this exception?

Comment: ML.NET 2.0 had a breaking change where it removed System.Drawing and replaced it with MLImage, so this may be issue - https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/main/docs/release-notes/2.0/release-2.0.0.md#breaking-changes

Answer (score 0):

As Jon commented, in order to get rid of the exception all the Bitmaps have to be removed and changed using Microsoft.ML.MLImage. Once it is done, and the code is changed accordingly, I managed get the code working again. Thank you!